# Portable SQLite ODBC Driver?

Tags: sqlite, odbc, portability

I don't see this exact topic, so here goes. I am designing a Portable app that lives on a thumb drive and is not Installed on the host device. My app uses SQLite as a DB. I, of course, need a SQLite ODBC Driver.

Is there such a thing or a way to make either Christian Werner's or Devart's SQLite ODBC driver portable, so it does not need to be installed on the host device?

Thank you for your time and advice. I do appreciate it.

Kent in KC

Comment: Why do you say that you "of course" need an SQLite ODBC driver.  SQLite is meant to be embedded in a application, so it's not obvious you need an ODBC driver at all.

Comment: ODBC drivers must be installed and are never portable.

Comment: I'm a retired guy, a VB6/MS Access/SQL Server coder by vocation. SQLite is new to me, although I must say I think it is really cool. I have a prototype I built in MS Access 2016 because, well, it's a prototype and Access is quick and easy and I know it cold and have tons of developer tools so, hey. Anyway, I need to couple my Access front end to the SQLite back end, although they are both on a thumbdrive. 
I need an ODBC driver to translate between VBA and SQL, basically. I know I can store the Direct Connect strings on my table links to avoid the use of DNS's but I still need an ODBC driver.

Comment: Anybody else care to comment?